# Finding an item in a list with maximum value

Tags: vb.net, list, max

I m a beginner in VB.Net. In the code I m working on, there is a class called Market with an attribute of Demand (integer). I have made a list of all instances of Market. At some point in the code, I need to find the Market instance in the list with highest demand value. How can I do that efficiently (without looping over all members of the list and comparing their demand with the lowest found value).
Thank you for your help 
Good day!

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code segment you're referring to.

Comment: You are right, sorry. I ll remember for the next question. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `OrderByDescending` method to sort the `List` by the Demand property and then select the first item.

```
    Dim markets As New List(Of Market)
    markets.Add(New Market With {.Demand = 10})
    markets.Add(New Market With {.Demand = 30})
    markets.Add(New Market With {.Demand = 20})
    Dim topMarket As Market = markets.OrderByDescending(Function(m) m.Demand).FirstOrDefault
```

Comment: @Helia on SO, "thanks" is shown by clicking the checkmark, and later (when you get 15 rep) clicking the UpArrow

Comment: Another question: suppose that markets have another attribute which is Boolean (lets call it Available). How to find the instance of market in the Markets list whose demand is maximum while its Available attribute is true? Thanks

Comment: @Helia This would probably be shorter in LINQ query format, but I'll stick to the same format as my asnswer. You can use the `Where` method to select only items that pass a test. `Dim topMarket As Market = markets.Where(Function(m) m.Available).OrderByDescending(Function(m) m.Demand).FirstOrDefault`

Answer (score 2):

Use Linq.  Here's a small example.  I tried to use the variable names you specified.  Not sure what you called your list, so I just called it MarketList

```
Public Class Form1
Private MarketList As List(Of Market)
Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()
    MarketList = New List(Of Market)()
    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    RunIt()
End Sub
Private Sub RunIt()
    Dim oMarket As New Market()
    oMarket.Demand = 0
    MarketList.Add(oMarket)
    oMarket = New Market()
    oMarket.Demand = 1
    MarketList.Add(oMarket)
    oMarket = New Market()
    oMarket.Demand = 2
    MarketList.Add(oMarket)

    Dim oMax As Market = (From mrkt As Market In MarketList Select mrkt Order By mrkt.Demand).Last()
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Market List has: {0} members" + vbNewLine + "Maximum Demand: {1}", MarketList.Count.ToString(), iMax.Demand.ToString()))
End Sub
Public Class Market
    Private _dmd As Integer
    Public Property Demand() As Integer
        Get
            Return _dmd
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _dmd = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

I edited it per your request.  You're basically doing the same thing the answer you accepted is doing, just in a slightly different way.  Anyway, here's an alternative for you or someone else that comes along.

Comment: Hi Aaron, Thanks for your reply.Just a question, using the suggested LINQ by you, I can find the max demand value while I want to find the Market instance with the MAX demand value. Can your code be changed to perform this task ? The method suggested below by Blackwood, works well of course.Thanks

Comment: You can do it.  I'm driving.  Give me an hour