# Min and max from list collection

Tags: vb.net, ienumerable

How can I get the min value ad max value from this example

```
Public Class RowsFound
    Property RowIndex As integer
    Property Qty As Integer
    Property LineValue As Double
End Class
Dim Test as new List(Of RowsFound)
```

above you can see the structure to my list. This is what the data would look like. 
[image]

What would be the best way to get the RowIndex based on max LineValue and RowIndex of Min LineValue

I have done this as a test but would like to see if there a better way of doing this.

```
                        Dim MaxRow As Integer = 0
                        Dim MaxRowValue As Integer = 0
                        Dim MinRow As Integer = 999999
                        Dim MinRowValue As Integer = 999999
                        For Each MinMaxitem As RowsFound In ListOfRows
                            If MinMaxitem.LineValue < MinRowValue Then
                                MinRow = MinMaxitem.RowIndex
                                MinRowValue = MinMaxitem.LineValue
                            End If
                            If MinMaxitem.LineValue > MaxRowValue Then
                                MaxRow = MinMaxitem.RowIndex
                                MaxRowValue = MinMaxitem.LineValue
                            End If
                        Next
```

Thank you :)

Comment: have you tried anything?  what is the meaning of "best"?  Least code? Fastest executing? Easiest to maintain?

Comment: yes, I would say least and fastest would be perfect. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35301862/finding-an-item-in-a-list-with-maximum-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to do this would be to use LINQ:

```
Public Class RowsFound
    Property RowIndex As Integer
    Property Qty As Integer
    Property LineValue As Double
    Public Sub New(i As Integer, q As Integer, v As Double)
        Me.RowIndex = i
        Me.Qty = q
        Me.LineValue = v
    End Sub
End Class
Dim Test As New List(Of RowsFound) From {New RowsFound(0, 1, 105.25), New RowsFound(1, 2, 100), New RowsFound(2, 1, 110), New RowsFound(3, 2, 60.25)}


Dim RowIndexMax As Integer = (From row As RowsFound In Test.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.LineValue) Select row.RowIndex).First
Dim RowindexMin As Integer = (From row As RowsFound In Test.OrderBy(Function(x) x.LineValue) Select row.RowIndex).First
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use Lambda Expressions:

1. first find the maximum \ Minimum value of `LineValue` using `Max()` and  `Min()`
2. find the index of the desired value using `FindIndex()`

   ```
   Private Function getMaxValueIndex() As Integer
   Dim maxValue As Integer = Test.Max(Function(t) t.LineValue)
   Dim maxValueIndex As Integer = Test.FindIndex(Function(t) t.LineValue = maxValue)
   Return maxValueIndex
   End Function

   Private Function getMinValueIndex() As Integer
   Dim minValue As Integer = Test.Min(Function(t) t.LineValue)
   Dim minValueIndex As Integer = Test.FindIndex(Function(t) t.LineValue = minValue)
   Return minValueIndex
   End Function
   ```